# Not all points are within the bounds of the space error in Scikit-Optimize

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, deep-learning, bayesian, hyperparameters

I am attempting to do a hyper-parameter optimization task on a LSTM model (purly Tensorflow) using the [scikit optimize package](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/). I am using the [Bayesian optimization method using Gaussian Processes](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/#skopt.gp_minimize) (gp_minimize) for this. The demo code provided for the function can be found through [this link](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/19_Hyper-Parameters.ipynb). When I try to run my code I keep getting the below error:

> ValueError: Not all points are within the bounds of the space.

My complete code is shown below:

```
import skopt
from skopt import gp_minimize, forest_minimize
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer
from skopt.plots import plot_convergence
from skopt.plots import plot_objective, plot_evaluations
from skopt.utils import use_named_args

import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import  pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
import atexit
from time import time, strftime, localtime
from datetime import timedelta


input_size = 1
num_layers = 1
hidden1_activation = tf.nn.relu
hidden2_activation = tf.nn.relu
lstm_activation = tf.nn.relu
columns = ['Sales', 'DayOfWeek', 'SchoolHoliday', 'Promo']
features = len(columns)
fileName = None
column_min_max = None


# fileNames = ['store2_1.csv', 'store85_1.csv', 'store259_1.csv', 'store519_1.csv', 'store725_1.csv', 'store749_1.csv', 'store934_1.csv', 'store1019_1.csv']
# column_min_max_all = [[[0, 11000], [1, 7]], [[0, 17000], [1, 7]], [[0, 23000], [1, 7]], [[0, 14000], [1, 7]], [[0, 14000], [1, 7]], [[0, 15000], [1, 7]], [[0, 17000], [1, 7]], [[0, 25000], [1, 7]]]

fileNames = ['store2_1.csv']
column_min_max_all = [[[0, 11000], [1, 7]]]



num_steps = None
lstm_size = None
batch_size = None
init_learning_rate = 0.01
learning_rate_decay = None
init_epoch = None  # 5
max_epoch = None  # 100 or 50
hidden1_nodes = None
hidden2_nodes = None
dropout_rate= None
best_accuracy = 0.0
start = None


lstm_num_steps = Categorical(categories=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14], name ='lstm_num_steps')
size = Categorical(categories=[8,16,32,64,128], name ='size')
lstm_hidden1_nodes = Categorical(categories=[4,8,16,32,64], name= 'lstm_hidden1_nodes')
lstm_hidden2_nodes = Categorical(categories=[2,4,8,16,32],name= 'lstm_hidden2_nodes')
lstm_learning_rate_decay = Categorical(categories=[0.99,0.8,0.7], name='lstm_learning_rate_decay')
lstm_max_epoch = Categorical(categories=[60,50,100,120,150,200], name='lstm_max_epoch')
lstm_init_epoch = Categorical(categories=[5, 10, 15, 20],name='lstm_init_epoch')
lstm_batch_size = Categorical(categories=[5, 8, 16, 30, 31, 64] , name = 'lstm_batch_size')
lstm_dropout_rate = Categorical(categories=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9] , name = 'lstm_dropout_rate')


dimensions = [lstm_num_steps, size,lstm_hidden1_nodes, lstm_hidden2_nodes,lstm_init_epoch,lstm_max_epoch,lstm_learning_rate_decay,lstm_batch_size, lstm_dropout_rate]

default_parameters = [5,35,30,15,5,60,0.99,8,0.1]



# def log_dir_name(lstm_num_steps, size,lstm_hidden1_nodes, lstm_hidden2_nodes,lstm_learning_rate,lstm_init_epoch,lstm_max_epoch,lstm_learning_rate_decay,lstm_batch_size):
#
#     # The dir-name for the TensorBoard log-dir.
#     s = "./19_logs/{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}_{6}_{7}_{8}_{9}/"
#
#     # Insert all the hyper-parameters in the dir-name.
#     log_dir = s.format(lstm_num_steps, size,lstm_hidden1_nodes, lstm_hidden2_nodes,lstm_learning_rate,lstm_init_epoch,lstm_max_epoch,lstm_learning_rate_decay,lstm_batch_size)
#
#     return log_dir

def secondsToStr(elapsed=None):
    if elapsed is None:
        return strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())
    else:
        return str(timedelta(seconds=elapsed))

def log(s, elapsed=None):
    line = "="*40
    print(line)
    print(secondsToStr(), '-', s)
    if elapsed:
        print("Elapsed time:", elapsed)
    print(line)
    print()

def endlog():
    end = time()
    elapsed = end-start
    log("End Program", secondsToStr(elapsed))


def generate_batches(train_X, train_y, batch_size):
    num_batches = int(len(train_X)) // batch_size
    if batch_size * num_batches < len(train_X):
        num_batches += 1

    batch_indices = range(num_batches)
    for j in batch_indices:
        batch_X = train_X[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        batch_y = train_y[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        # assert set(map(len, batch_X)) == {num_steps}
        yield batch_X, batch_y


def segmentation(data):

    seq = [price for tup in data[columns].values for price in tup]

    seq = np.array(seq)

    # split into items of features
    seq = [np.array(seq[i * features: (i + 1) * features])
           for i in range(len(seq) // features)]

    # split into groups of num_steps
    X = np.array([seq[i: i + num_steps] for i in range(len(seq) -  num_steps)])

    y = np.array([seq[i +  num_steps] for i in range(len(seq) -  num_steps)])

    # get only sales value
    y = [[y[i][0]] for i in range(len(y))]

    y = np.asarray(y)

    return X, y

def scale(data):

    for i in range (len(column_min_max)):
        data[columns[i]] = (data[columns[i]] - column_min_max[i][0]) / ((column_min_max[i][1]) - (column_min_max[i][0]))

    return data

def rescle(test_pred):

    prediction = [(pred * (column_min_max[0][1] - column_min_max[0][0])) + column_min_max[0][0] for pred in test_pred]

    return prediction


def pre_process():
    store_data = pd.read_csv(fileName)
    # sftp://wso2@192.168.32.11/home/wso2/suleka/salesPred/store2_1.csv


    store_data = store_data.drop(store_data[(store_data.Open == 0) & (store_data.Sales == 0)].index)
    #
    # store_data = store_data.drop(store_data[(store_data.Open != 0) & (store_data.Sales == 0)].index)

    # ---for segmenting original data --------------------------------
    original_data = store_data.copy()

    ## train_size = int(len(store_data) * (1.0 - test_ratio))



    validation_len = len(store_data[(store_data.Month == 6) & (store_data.Year == 2015)].index)
    test_len = len(store_data[(store_data.Month == 7) & (store_data.Year == 2015)].index)
    train_size = int(len(store_data) -  (validation_len+test_len))

    train_data = store_data[:train_size]
    validation_data = store_data[(train_size-num_steps): validation_len+train_size]
    test_data = store_data[((validation_len+train_size) - num_steps): ]
    original_val_data = validation_data.copy()
    original_test_data = test_data.copy()


    # -------------- processing train data---------------------------------------
    scaled_train_data = scale(train_data)
    train_X, train_y = segmentation(scaled_train_data)

    # -------------- processing validation data---------------------------------------
    scaled_validation_data = scale(validation_data)
    val_X, val_y = segmentation(scaled_validation_data)


    # -------------- processing test data---------------------------------------
    scaled_test_data = scale(test_data)
    test_X, test_y = segmentation(scaled_test_data)

    # ----segmenting original validation data-----------------------------------------------
    nonescaled_val_X, nonescaled_val_y = segmentation(original_val_data)


    # ----segmenting original test data-----------------------------------------------
    nonescaled_test_X, nonescaled_test_y = segmentation(original_test_data)



    return train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y, val_X, val_y, nonescaled_test_y,nonescaled_val_y


def setupRNN(inputs):

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(lstm_size, state_is_tuple=True, activation=lstm_activation)

    val1, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

    val = tf.transpose(val1, [1, 0, 2])

    last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1, name="last_lstm_output")

    # hidden layer
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(last, units=hidden1_nodes, activation=hidden2_activation)
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, units=hidden2_nodes, activation=hidden1_activation)

    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(hidden2, rate=dropout_rate, training=True)

    weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden2_nodes, input_size]))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[input_size]))

    prediction = tf.matmul(dropout, weight) + bias

    return prediction



# saver = tf.train.Saver()
# saver.save(sess, "checkpoints_sales/sales_pred.ckpt")





@use_named_args(dimensions=dimensions)
def fitness(lstm_num_steps, size,lstm_hidden1_nodes,lstm_hidden2_nodes,lstm_init_epoch,lstm_max_epoch,
           lstm_learning_rate_decay,lstm_batch_size,lstm_dropout_rate):

    global num_steps, lstm_size, hidden2_nodes, hidden2_activation, hidden1_activation, hidden1_nodes, lstm_activation, init_epoch, max_epoch, learning_rate_decay, dropout_rate

    num_steps = lstm_num_steps
    lstm_size = size
    batch_size = lstm_batch_size
    learning_rate_decay = lstm_learning_rate_decay
    init_epoch = lstm_init_epoch
    max_epoch = lstm_max_epoch
    hidden1_nodes = lstm_hidden1_nodes
    hidden2_nodes = lstm_hidden2_nodes
    dropout_rate = lstm_dropout_rate


    # log_dir = log_dir_name(lstm_num_steps, size,lstm_hidden1_nodes,lstm_hidden2_nodes,lstm_learning_rate,lstm_init_epoch,lstm_max_epoch,
    #        lstm_learning_rate_decay,lstm_batch_size)

    train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y, val_X, val_y, nonescaled_test_y, nonescaled_val_y = pre_process()

    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_steps, features], name="inputs")
    targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size], name="targets")
    learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None, name="learning_rate")

    prediction = setupRNN(inputs)

    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        model_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(targets, prediction)

    with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(model_loss)

    train_step = train_step

    # with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    #     correct_prediction = tf.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(prediction, targets))
    #
    # accuracy = correct_prediction

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    learning_rates_to_use = [
        init_learning_rate * (
                learning_rate_decay ** max(float(i + 1 - init_epoch), 0.0)
        ) for i in range(max_epoch)]

    for epoch_step in range(max_epoch):

        current_lr = learning_rates_to_use[epoch_step]


        for batch_X, batch_y in generate_batches(train_X, train_y, batch_size):
            train_data_feed = {
                inputs: batch_X,
                targets: batch_y,
                learning_rate: current_lr,
            }

            sess.run(train_step, train_data_feed)

    val_data_feed = {
        inputs: val_X,
        targets: val_y,
        learning_rate: 0.0,
    }

    pred = sess.run(prediction, val_data_feed)

    pred_vals = rescle(pred)

    pred_vals = np.array(pred_vals)

    pred_vals = pred_vals.flatten()

    pred_vals = pred_vals.tolist()

    nonescaled_y = nonescaled_val_y.flatten()

    nonescaled_y = nonescaled_y.tolist()

    val_accuracy = sqrt(mean_squared_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals))

    global best_accuracy

    if val_accuracy < best_accuracy:
        # Save the new model to harddisk.
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(sess, "checkpoints_sales/sales_pred.ckpt")

        with open("best_configs.csv", "a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(zip([fileName], [num_steps], [lstm_size], [hidden2_nodes], [hidden2_activation], [hidden1_activation], [hidden1_nodes], [lstm_size], [lstm_activation],  [init_epoch], [max_epoch], [learning_rate_decay], [dropout_rate],[val_accuracy]))

        # Update the classification accuracy.
        best_accuracy = val_accuracy

    # Clear the Keras session, otherwise it will keep adding new
    # models to the same TensorFlow graph each time we create
    # a model with a different set of hyper-parameters.
    # sess.clear_session()
    sess.close()
    tf.reset_default_graph()


    # NOTE: Scikit-optimize does minimization so it tries to
    # find a set of hyper-parameters with the LOWEST fitness-value.
    # Because we are interested in the HIGHEST classification
    # accuracy, we need to negate this number so it can be minimized.
    return val_accuracy


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time()

    for i in range(len(fileNames)):

        fileName = '{}{}'.format('home/suleka/Documents/sales_prediction/', fileNames[i])
        #/home/suleka/Documents/sales_prediction/


        column_min_max = column_min_max_all[i]

        #Bayesian optimization using Gaussian Processes.
        #acq_func -> https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02811.pdf

        search_result = gp_minimize(func=fitness,
                                dimensions=dimensions,
                                acq_func='EI', # Expected Improvement.
                                n_calls=40,
                                x0=default_parameters)

    atexit.register(endlog)
    log("Start Program")
```

Shown below is the complete stack trace:

> /home/wso2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/**init**.py:36:
>   FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from
>   `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated
>   as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.   from ._conv import
>   register_converters as _register_converters auto_LSTM_skopt.py:138:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   data[columns[i]] = (data[columns[i]] - column_min_max[i][0]) /
>   ((column_min_max[i](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/)) - (column_min_max[i][0]))
>   /home/wso2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:100:
>   UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of
>   unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
>   "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "auto_LSTM_skopt.py", line
>   365, in 
>       x0=default_parameters)   File "/home/wso2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt/optimizer/gp.py",
>   line 228, in gp_minimize
>       callback=callback, n_jobs=n_jobs)   File "/home/wso2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt/optimizer/base.py",
>   line 240, in base_minimize
>       result = optimizer.tell(x0, y0)   File "/home/wso2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt/optimizer/optimizer.py",
>   line 432, in tell
>       check_x_in_space(x, self.space)   File "/home/wso2/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt/utils.py",
>   line 186, in check_x_in_space
>       raise ValueError("Not all points are within the bounds of" ValueError: Not all points are within the bounds of the space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue is with your **size** dimension. All values in default_parameters **must** be in the lists of the parameter dimensions to be optimized, if not `skopt` throws the *Not all points are within the bounds of the space error*.

You currently have: `size = Categorical(categories=[8,16,32,64,128], name ='size')`

In your default parameters: `default_parameters = [5,35,30,15,5,60,0.99,8,0.1]`

the second item (representing 'size') has the value of 35, which is not part of the size parameters to search.

**FIX 1**.
Include 35 in size space:

`size = Categorical(categories=[8,16,32,35,64,128], name ='size')`

**FIX 2**.
Change 35 to '32' in default_parameters:

`default_parameters = [5,32,30,15,5,60,0.99,8,0.1]`

Use any of the fixes above and your code will run like a charm :)